# what is the best way to send an js object to firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using functional component of **react native** fully. I've been using it for about 1 week now but I'm still trying to get used to typescript.
So I have written a functional component of a TextInput called `StyledTextInput`, I have no idea if I am in the right direction, I use `React.useState<string>("");` in the parent to update the text, however I noticed there is a slight delay when updating the text.
I have a simple signup form, which will only be used 1 time:

1. phone number
2. gender
3. occupation
4. favoriteColor
5. favoriteSong

```
const [num, setNum]       = React.useState<number>(0);
const [gender, setGender] = React.useState<string>("");
const [job, setJob]       = React.useState<string>("");
const [color, setColor]   = React.useState<string>("");
const [song, setSong]     = React.useState<string>("");
```

So base on firebase documentation I see sending request is using Javascript Object right? https://rnfirebase.io/app/usage so to send an object I can imagine it look something like this?

```
function sendObject(){
    const sendThis = { num: num, gender: gender, job: job, color: color, song: song };

    firebase.database().ref(url).push(sendThis).
}
```

The problem is there is some delay in `set` of `useState`. I am not looking for external library, I know there are external library like https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form but how do they store edit and send the object? 
Is there a more elegant way to make sure the `sendThis` object is up to date? I am wondering is it possible to pass the object to the `StyledTextInput` and update the value accordingly? Please guide me how.

Comment: recently started with react, typescript and firebase. Just in case it helps, afaik, the way to add a register to the firestore woud be like this: `const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection('collectionName').add({ collectionObject })`

Comment: no, just reactjs. Just mentioning it in case it might be helpful

Comment: why don't you do this? firestore().doc("collectionName").set(collectionObject) @rustyBucketBay

Comment: beacuase I want to add the element to the collection